# Pymongo Cursor Iteration Bottleneck

Tags: python, mongodb, list, pymongo, database-cursor

I am trying to convert this MongoDB Cursor() object returned from the "nearest" query to a list datatype. This appears to be a bottleneck in my code. I am looking for this operation to be done in just a few milliseconds. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
nearest = self.database_objs[common_models.ObjModel().current_geographic_collection].find({"location": {
            "$geoWithin": {
                "$centerSphere": [start, self.distance_radians(self.feet_meter(radius))]}}})

print(list(nearest)) # problem here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `find` just set a cursor to the first point the query is satisfied (it searches through the collection and stops on the first document that satisfies the conditions).
`list(nearest)` evaluate the result and loads **all** the documents from the mongodb cursor to your RAM. If you have a lot of documents in your result query, it will take some time to load them.
You can [limit](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) your result and it will be faster.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Is there a way to return a list() datatype instead of the Cursor()?

Comment: No, you always get a cursor.